# what dose the transacted parameter means of QueueConnection.createQueueSession(boolean transacted, int acknowledgeMode)

Tags: transactions, queue, jms

in JMS API, we've below method 
QueueConnection.createQueueSession(boolean transacted,  int acknowledgeMode)

I'm wondering what exactly does the transacted parameter means?
I know when set it as true, we need to call QueueSession.commit() method after finish sending or receiving, 
but how about set it to false? does this means the sending/receiving operations is not trustable? or it's still ok?, if it's still ok, then why do we need to difference the cases?

or set it to true is only for cases that we need to put multiple messages in one transaction?
thx.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter indicates whether the QueueSession is transacted or not. A value of true indicates that the session is transacted, meaning that messages sent to queues during the lifespan of the QueueSession will not be delivered to the receivers until the commit method is invoked on the QueueSession. Likewise, invoking the rollback method on the QueueSession will remove any messages sent during the transacted session

Answer (score 0):

This [Java Developer's Journal](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Java/archives/0604/chappell/index.html) article covers that quite extensively — particular acknowledge mode/session transacted settings combinations are explained there.

Comment: thx, i think it talked detail about set it to true, which means transactional; but it did not cover cases about false, would you explain what does setting non-transactional messages mean?